# Display children of one parent page on home page (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a loop that is displaying all pages (not posts) on my home page. I want to modify the loop so that it'll only display the children of a single parent page (the page id number is 116, just for reference). How should I modify the code below to do this?

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=page&posts_per_page=-1'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"
    rel="bookmark"  title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
    <div>  

        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>

            <div ><?php the_title(); ?>
        </div>  <!-- headlines-title -->

    </div></a>

<?php  endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Also wanted to add that displaying grandchildren is OK, too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed course and got the results I wanted this way:

```
<?php
$pages = get_pages('child_of=129&sort_column=post_date&sort_order=desc');
$count = 0;
foreach($pages as $page)
{
$content = $page->post_content;
?>


<a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" >
    <div >  


        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'thumbnail'); ?>

    <div><?php echo $page->post_title ?>
        </div>
    </div></a>



<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php query_posts('static=true&child_limit=10&child_of='.$id.'&order=ASC'); ?>
<?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?>:</a><?php the_excerpt(); ? >
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

$id is your page id

Comment: Put the parent page id in, and it didn't display any pages at all.

Comment: sorry you must install this plugin to work http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/pjw-query-child-of/

Comment: Found an answer that doesn't necessitate installing the plugin. Thanks for the help, though.